# Looking for a way to change the app name under "open with" menu , use multiple names for the same app

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am developing an app for macOS that can for example open zip and jpg file.
I am using the following code to associate the file type with my app -

```
  OSStatus returnStatus = LSSetDefaultRoleHandlerForContentType ((CFStringRef) [self UTIforFileExtension:fileExtension], kLSRolesAll,(CFStringRef) bundleIdentifier);
```

I want to see different app names under "Open with" menu.
For example - if i right click on .zip file i want to see "zip opener" and if i right click on .jpg file i want to see "jpg opener"
Again i am using the same app to do both actions.
Is it possible? or because it is determined by the Bundle Name it is not possible?

Comment: It seems that you are simply making a request instead of building an app of your own.  I would wait till Christmas if I were you.

Comment: Hi, sorry but I have an app ready. I only need to figure out how do to the specific things I asked about